# What is the reward for keeping the Prejek Paddle Fish alive?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The official Prima guide notes that if Shepard purchased a Prejek Paddle Fish in ME2, and kept it alive all the way through to the end of ME3, that when starting a New Game+, there would be a special additional Intel bonus available at the terminal in Liara's cabin aboard the Normandy.

I don't have a save available in which I could convince Kelly to feed my fish for me, and thus, all of my ME2 fish are now Krogan food. **What is the reward for keeping my finned friend alive?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the screenshots in this BioWare forum post](http://social.bioware.com/forum/Mass-Effect-3/Mass-Effect-3-Gameplay-Strategy-amp-Builds-Discussion-Spoilers-allowed/Prejek-Paddlefish-Intel-9809455-1.html) (and mentioned in [another thread, by another player](http://social.bioware.com/forum/Mass-Effect-3/Mass-Effect-3-Story-and-Campaign-Discussion-Spoilers-Allowed/Secret-Prejek-Paddle-Fish-Secret-Intel-9744663-1.html#9744869)), the reward is a 10% power or weapon damage bonus.

The intel is listed as "Prejek Paddlefish" in the terminal, and has the following description:

> This fish is a rare and valuable subspecies of the prejek paddlefish, prized for its rich and savory flavor. The breed is endangered, and a member of the Hanar Illuminated Primacy is offering a choice of rewards in exchange for the fish.

Comment: I may award my bounty in 23 hours.